# Ubuntu 19.04 booting up into black screen

Tags: dual-boot, 19.04

[image]

I installed (dual booted) Ubuntu 19.04 yesterday and booted it 2 or 3 times but when I booted today it is showing a black screen and nothing.

Comment: problem with drivers maybe

Comment: @Gowthaman give me solutions dude